# Android WifiP2p not working when 3g is active

Tags: android, bind, 3g, wifip2p

I have been working with WifiP2p on Android devices ( Tested with both Lollipop and Marshmallow) and I have experienced a problem with connection in some cases.

**Problem** : For some reason, when 3g(Data) and WifiP2p are connected in same time, two Android devices that are connected via WifiP2p can't exchange data between them. ( Try SuperBeam application with two Android devices)

**Scenarios :**

- **Working** -> Device is connected on Wifi network and is connected on WifiP2p
- **Working** -> Device is connected only on WifiP2p
- **Not Working** -> Device is connected on 3g(Data) and is connected on WifiP2p

**Tried solution** : Possible solution was to bind on the WifiP2p Network. But there is another problem. This call `connectivityManager.getAllNetworks()` never returns active WifiP2p Network and this call `connectivityManager.requestNetwork(....)` never receives WifiP2p Network `onAvailable()` and this call : `connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo()` never returns network info about active WifiP2p connection.

Does anybody have some suggestion for this problem ?

P.S. We can vote here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193030 to google solve the issue.